# Streaming a call voice on android?

Tags: android, call, recorder

After a bit of googling I came to know that recording a call in android is not possible maybe because of some legal reasons, But I want to know whether its's possible to stream the call voice from android, I dont't want to record it, just want to tether it for some functionality requirement..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not possible? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.record.my.call&hl=en does just that

Comment: ohhh tht was a ray of hope :)..thnx for pointing that out, also would like to know some technical details or any api that provides this functionality...

Comment: I am sorry. I dont think I can help you with that as i have absolutely no clue how to do it. But if you post that as a new question I am pretty sure someone out there can help you.